# How can I debug a PHP Web Application's (Magento specifically) Installation Flow? 

Tags: php, javascript, magento

I can't get passed the Magento Installer's Terms of Service. After clicking the *Accept* check box and clicking *Submit*, the page (seemingly?) refreshes itself.

I’ve changed perms to 0777 with this script

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
chmod o+w var/.htaccess
chmod 550 mage
```

and also tried disabling the script with no avail.

I am installing from http://www.mydomain.org/2/index.php/install/wizard/beginPost/
with no avail, I thought I would mention the path just in case.

Is this a common problem with the system? If not, how can I debug what's going on?

**UNSOLVED (this only took care of one issue, there is evidently more issues afoot)**

**EDIT** There seems to be an issue with possibly **getPost** in not properly passing the argument correctly?

Comment: The page is constantly refreshing itself or you got the "redirect loop" message from your browser?

Comment: I'm fairly sure it is redirecting without the loop message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install via CLI to get around the web based installer issues (usually), I've encountered some anomalies before when installing:  http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/command_line_installation_wizard

It may help also shed some light on why the web based installer isn't working if any errors are thrown, both during installation and after.

You can also try: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-know-if-my-server-is-compatible-with-magento to ensure your server is meeting proper requirements.

Comment: Via command line I was able to troubleshoot my way through the install.

Answer (score 3):

Your post is thin on the details someone would need to debug this for you.  Two tips.

1. You shouldn't be starting the install on `install/wizard/beginPost`.  Instead, just load the root level domain name with no path, and let Magento direct you where it needs you to go (you may already be doing this)
2. The installer, like the rest of Magento, is a Module, which you may debug.  Its controller is located at `app/code/core/Mage/Install/controllers/WizardController.php`

Adding temporary debugging code into the `beginAction` and `beginPostAction` to figure out what's going on is your best bet

Comment: And if you feel that it is JS (judging from the tag you gave) redirect it may be useful looking into Firebug flow.

Comment: @Alan: The install.php actually reroutes to install/wizard/beginPost fyi  @Gordon: I looked through Firebug but saw no issues...?

Comment: @Alan: After going to www.domain.org/2 (installation directory) I will to the agree to above terms, click continue and will be forwarded to www.domain.org/2/index.php/install/wizard/beginPost/ again, it's looping me.

Comment: By commenting out the auth portion I was able to bypass the issues

Comment: @Alan, for some reason it seems that the Data is not **POSTing** I believe that this is the reason that we're (aka: I am) having issues. It does not seem to pass the **getPost** correctly?

Comment: @ehime: I have no idea.  If your install isn't running correctly it speaks to some file being modified on your system, or Magento running abnormally in your environment.  I don't know the install system intimately, so there's no way to answer this sort of question on a forum.